# AJAX Only Runs On First Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage that dynamically creates URLs on page load. The first time these links are clicked, they call a ajax query to load page data and it works perfectly. However, the second time the query is not executed and the data remains the same from the previous load.

Here is HTML code in **activitylog.aspx** where the URL items are added:

```
<ul class="ver-inline-menu tabbable margin-bottom-10 incidentlist"></ul>
```

Here is the jQuery Code in **activitylog.aspx** that is run on startup:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get Parameter Values
    var paramShiftId = getURLParameter('shift_id');
    var paramIncidentId = getURLParameter('incident_id');

    // Run Data Handler Query
    $.ajax({
        url: "queries/dataHandler_getShiftInfo.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { shift_id: paramShiftId, incident_id: paramIncidentId },
        responseType: "json",
        success: OnViewComplete,
        error: OnViewFail
    });
    return false;

    function OnViewComplete(result) {

        //Cycle Through JSON Rows
        $.each(result.aaData, function (i, row) {
             $(".incidentlist").append("<li><a href=\"activitylog.aspx?shift_id=" + row.SHIFT_ID + "&incident_id=" + row.INCIDENT_ID + "\">" + row.INC_NUMBER + " </a></li>");
        }
     }


});
```

How do I create dynamic URLs that will load a refreshed page each time?

Comment: " the second time the query is not executed" - what query?

Comment: Where is the on click event handler?

Comment: what does `return false;` do in `$(document).ready(function () {`?

Comment: @Igor The query is run at page startup. So when the <a href> link is pressed, the page is reloaded with new paramters. The first time the page is refreshed with data. The second time, the data is the same even if it has changed.

Comment: @Chris There is no event handler. It is a standard HTML URL that reloads the same page with new parameters.

Comment: "The first time these links are clicked, they call a ajax query..." A click event handler would be required for that functionality...

Comment: @rak11 - what is the value of `href` attribute of the anchor that you click? what is the url in the browser address bar when the page reloads? do `paramShiftId` and `paramIncidentId` have correct values? does `dataHandler_getShiftInfo.ashx` receive them?

Comment: @Chris the event is handled at page startup.

Comment: The code you have posted will simply run on page load. Nothing else. The code wouldn't run again until you reloaded the page...

Comment: @Igor When the page reloads, the URL is `http://activitylog.aspx?shift_id=XXXX&incident_id=XXXX`. I know the parameters are accurate. I know the .ashx file works. When stepping through code, it makes it to the ajax block, but does not execute the second time.

Comment: @Chris Even when the page reloads, the AJAX query does not run. Literally - it runs the first time the page is loaded with parameters. But if the same parameters are loaded, the query does not load.

Comment: `console.log( result )` in your ajax success callback

Comment: "AJAX query does not run"? Do you mean code execution does not reach dataHandler_getShiftInfo.ashx? Any errors in console? does `OnViewFail` fire?

Comment: `but does not execute the second time` because nobody call it second time...

Comment: How are you invent this? Why do you need to reload a page to make a new **ajax** call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is something about `no need to reload a page`...

```
$(function(){
    var paramShiftId = getURLParameter('shift_id');
    var paramIncidentId = getURLParameter('incident_id');
    loadData(paramShiftId, paramIncidentId);
})();


function loadData(paramShiftId, paramIncidentId) {

    // Run Data Handler Query
    $.ajax({
        url: "queries/dataHandler_getShiftInfo.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { shift_id: paramShiftId, incident_id: paramIncidentId},
        responseType: "json",
        success: OnViewComplete,
        error: OnViewFail
      });
}

function OnViewComplete(result) {
    $.each(result.aaData, function (i, row) {
         $(".incidentlist").append("<li><a href=\"javascript:loadData("+row.SHIFT_ID+","+row.INCIDENT_ID+")\">" + row.INC_NUMBER + " </a></li>");
    });
}
function OnViewFail(err){console.error(err);}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This definitely helps. I also added in `cache: false` in the ajax options to ensure the query is refreshed each time.